# Convert between list of 3D coordinates and 2D array

Tags: fitting, data, list-manipulation, data-structures

I have a dataset that I import from a csv file. It's a rectangular array of values, with the first row and first column specifying the x and y coordinates. I want fit this data to a 2D function using `NonlinearModelFit`. It seems that for `NonlinearModelFit`, I need the data in the form `{{x1, y1, z1},{x2,y2,z2},...}`, but for plotting with `ListDensityPlot`, it is much faster to use data in the rectangular array form `{{z1, z2...},{...},...}`. My question is if there is a fast, efficient way to translate between these two data formats. My current solution is to make the coordinate form with something like

```
coordinateArray = Flatten[Table[{x[[i]], y[[j]], dataArray[[i,j]]},
                                {i,1,Length[x]},{j,1,Length[y]}],1]
```

and to go back with

```
dataArray = Partition[coordinateArray[[All, 3]], Length[y]]
```

These seem to work, but I'm wondering if there's a better way or if there's a way to avoid this altogether with some option of `NonlinearModelFit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first transformation given in the question.

```
coordinateArray = Flatten[Table[{x[[i]], y[[j]], dataArray[[i, j]]}, 
    {i, 1, Length[x]}, {j, 1, Length[y]}], 1];
```

is quite efficient, requiring only 1.6 sec on my PC to transform a million element array.  It is, however, possible to obtain the same result more quickly with

```
coordinateArray = MapThread[Append[#1, #2] &, {Tuples[{x, y}], Flatten[dataArray]}];
```

which requires only 0.7 sec.  (`Tuples` generates all combinations `{x, y}`, and `Append` attaches corresponding `z` values.)  Incidentally, `Flatten[Outer[List, x, y], 1]` is equivalent to `Tuples[{x, y}]` and `Join[#1, {#2}] &` is only about 15% slower than `Append[#1, #2] &`

The inverse transformation given in the question requires only 0.04 sec, and I have found nothing faster.

Answer (score 0):

I want to address your definition of your table format and the way that you reading the CSV data.  From your code, you are reading from sequence item 1. But this is meaningless because the first row and first column do not represent a coordinate position , therefore position {1,1} has no data.  here is a demo data to show better my point.

```
{{ 0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 6, 0}, {2, 7, -4, 0}, {3, 0, -3, 66}, {4, 0, 
   5, -3}} // MatrixForm
```

This is the format for a coordinate table you describe.

[image]

I exporter and imported this to test your scenario.

```
In[90]:= Export["jose", %, "CSV"]

Out[90]= "jose"

In[91]:= dataArray = Import["jose"]

Out[91]= {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 6, 0}, {2, 7, -4, 0}, {3, 0, -3, 
  66}, {4, 0, 5, -3}}
```

Then this table shall be read from the second sequence position.

```
Flatten[Table[{i, j, dataArray[[i + 1, j + 1]]}, {i, 
   Dimensions@dataArray - 1 // First}, {j, 
   Dimensions@dataArray - 1 // Last}], 1]
```

{{1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 3, 0}, {2, 1, 7}, {2, 2, -4}, {2, 3, 
  0}, {3, 1, 0}, {3, 2, -3}, {3, 3, 66}, {4, 1, 0}, {4, 2, 5}, {4, 
  3, -3}}